# In Notepad++, removing beginning text from each line?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have some junk before each line and the text I want

```
eernnawer love.pdf 
nawewera man.pdf
awettt sup.pdf
```

I would like to do a find and replace to get

```
love.pdf
man.pdf
sup.pdf
```

How can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the search and replace dialog
2. Activate *Regular Expressions* as search mode, check *Wrap around*
3. Find: `.* (.*\.pdf)$`
4. Replace: `\1`
5. Click *Replace All*

`\1` is the text found by the expression in the (first) pair of parentheses. If you would want to remove the trailing text, you could use `(.*) .*\.pdf$`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do ctrl+R
click the box for allowing RegEx
Insert ^[^\s]+\s into the top box
Then Find
Then Replace Rest

Answer (score 1):

You could find `^[^ ]*` and replace it with nothing (notice the space at the end of the regex).

Answer (score 0):

In Find and Replace in regular expression mode, find for `.*` (note, with a space in the end ) and replace with blank.